# What’s the correct scope value to use for an HTML <th> table cell than spans several columns?

Tags: html, html-table, accessibility

Say you’ve got an HTML table, with a `<th>` cell that spans several columns, e.g.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th colspan="3" scope="?">Scores</th>
        <!-- ...more headings here... -->
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th scope="col">English</th>
        <th scope="col">Maths</th>
        <th scope="col">Science</th>
        <!-- ...more sub-headings here... -->
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>12</td>
        <td>16</td>
        <td>20</td>
        <!-- ...more cells here... -->
    </tr>
</table>
```

What’s the correct value for the scope attribute for the spanning header cell? `col` seems incorrect as it’s heading several columns, but `colgroup` does’t seem right if I don’t actually have any `colgroup` tags.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the second example table in the HTML spec, it’s `colgroup`, despite the lack of `colgroup` tags.

http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/tables.html#h-11.4.1

Answer (score 9):

The WebAIM (Web Accessibility in Mind) group has a great article on [creating accessible data tables](http://www.webaim.org/techniques/tables/data.php). Overall, they recommend avoiding spanned rows or columns, as screen readers cannot interpret the markup reliably.

Short of avoiding spanned columns altogether, I've had really good luck using the id/headers attributes in combination with the scope attribute. Although the markup is more verbose, this seems to simplify things for JAWS, and as a result it has less trouble interpreting the data.

This is what your example would look like with id/headers:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th id="scores" colspan="3">Scores</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th id="english" scope="col">English</th>
        <th id="maths" scope="col">Maths</th>
        <th id="science" scope="col">Science</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td headers="scores english">12</td>
        <td headers="scores maths">16</td>
        <td headers="scores science">20</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Great stuff, thanks. I’d lean on the side of the screen readers supporting the spec rather than everyone coding to their quirks, but it’s great to document the quirks.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the caption feature may be better suited for you...

```
<table>
  <caption>Scores</caption>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">English</th>
      <th scope="col">Maths</th>
      <th scope="col">Science</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>12</td>
      <td>16</td>
      <td>20</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/caption

Comment: Ah — yes quite possibly. The actual use case I had in mind was a table with more columns than in my example HTML, so the heading that spans several columns didn’t actually span the entire table. I’ll amend the example accordingly.

Comment: Gotcha. Dave's response in using the ID's seems to be exactly what you were looking for. You know, 4 years ago :)